# Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “picture-in-picture” / “autoplay” / “encrypted-media”

Tags: javascript, security, firefox

I get this warning in Firefox using YouTube iframe js API

How to deal with this?

[image]

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube API is sending calls to the browser but the browser is responding saying "I don't support that" then letting you know in the console that it knocked back features because it had no support for the feature mentioned.

You specifically mention Firefox and highlight "encypted-media". This is a Feature which is not (at the time of writing) currently supported by Firefox or Safari. In Firefox you can go to about:config and switch it on but it doesn't do anything, even if you express .

I know the answer I have isn't what you want to hear but these warnings will keep happening unless you can tell the YouTube API not to request these Features or until Firefox supports them.

For more information check out

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy